# Date format in TJSONObject

Tags: json, c++builder, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I am converting a `TFDMemTable` to JSON via `SaveToStream()`. Then I use `TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue()` to get the JSON object.  After some parsing, I return the JSON in string format via `ToString()`.

```
  TStringStream *Stream = new TStringStream();
  TJSONObject *Json = new TJSONObject();

  fdMemTable->SaveToStream(Stream.get(), sfJSON);

  TJSONObject *JsonParsed = (TJSONObject*) Json->ParseJSONValue(Stream->DataString);
  ...    
  return JsonParsed->ToString();
```

All through this, the dates remain in the form `20180329T013152` instead of `2018-03-29T01:31:52`. I am looking to see if there is any option that I can set. `TJsonOptions` seems to be close to what I am looking for, but seems to only be used with `ObjectToJsonString()`.

Does anyone know any such option, or do I have to do this conversion per date/time field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no date/time type in JSON.  Date/time values are just arbitrary string values with formatting.  So, unless `TFDMemTable` provides an option to specify date/time formatting for its JSON output, then you will have to handle this on a per-field basis.

BTW, you don't need to create a `TJSONObject` object to call `ParseJSONValue()`:

```
TJSONObject *JsonParsed = (TJSONObject*) TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(Stream->DataString);
```